# What is the source of following fortran runtime error when I have used the correct WRITE DESCRIPTOR?

Tags: io, formatting, fortran

I was just making a program that reads values from a file that contains data and just uses it to calculate a simple function , then prints the output to another file.

I can't understand why it shows that it got character when I have used the **F** descriptor here.

```
program doppler_w_data

implicit none

real f
integer i,u,v,n

open(unit=1,file="inputfor_doppler.txt",status="old")
open(unit=2,file="outputfor_doppler.txt",status="old")

do i=1,5
read(1,1001) u,v,n

1001 format(4I5)

f = n*(330+u)/(330-v)

write(2,1002) "the req apparent freq is" ,f

1002 format(F9.4)

end do
endprogram doppler_w_data
```

The error is:

```
At line 18 of file doppler_w_data.f90 (unit = 2, file = 'outputfor_doppler.txt')
Fortran runtime error: Expected REAL for item 1 in formatted transfer, got CHARACTER
(F9.4)
 ^
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Please do not combine various tags for different Fortran standard versions if your questions is not about those particular versions in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not use the correct descriptor. The data for output is

```
  "the req apparent freq is"
```

and that is `CHARACTER`.

The descriptor is

```
  F9.4
```

and that is for the `REAL` numerical datatype.

Use the `A` descriptor for `CHARACTER` data.